# Trying to generate stub(java file) with json(application/json) data with file(multipart) using swagger

Tags: java, spring, file-upload, swagger-3.0

trying to submit form with multiple attachments(file)
whether it is correct approach or i don't know if i am using multipart/form-data not able to submit json data.

paths:
/request/create:
post:
tags:
- Request Service API
summary: request for media file access
security: []
operationId: createMediaRequest
parameters:
- name: userId
in: header
description: user login id
required: true
schema:
type: string
- name: xt-trace-id
in: header
description: request trace id
required: true
schema:
type: string

```
  requestBody:
    description: to send a request to get media file, id is mandatory for make a request. Id should be a valid and in the form of UUID.
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          type: object
          properties:
            deviceinfo:
              type: array
              items:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/ClientReqData'
            priority:
              type: string
              example: '1'
            appID:
              type: string
              example: 'app1'
            hostID:
              type: string
              example: 'host1'
            subscribers:
              type: string
              example: "[XT123,xt234]"
            requestreason:
              type: string
              example: "audit purpose"
            previousshiftemployee:
              type: string
              example: xyz
            regulationchecklist:
              type: string
              example: "[i have read instructions, I have identified]"
            file:
              type: array
              items:
                type: string
                format: binary
            attachments:
              type: array
              items:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Attachments'      
    required: true
    
    
  responses:
    201:
      description: Request for media created
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/CreateMediaResponse'
    400:
      $ref: '#/components/responses/400-bad-request'
    500:
      $ref: '#/components/responses/500-internal-server-error'
    503:
      $ref: '#/components/responses/503-Service-unavailable'
```

and Attachments is

```
Attachments:
  type: object
  properties:
    filename:
      type: string
      format: binary
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand you would like to create a stub for the HTTP endpoint defined in the Swagger specification. In other words, you are looking for creating an over-the-wire test double.

There are a couple of options you have:

- Use one of the [tools available on the market](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_API_simulation_tools)

  - Example of an OpenSource tool: [Wiremock](http://wiremock.org/). You can manually [configure it to simulate your HTTP APIs](https://www.infoq.com/articles/Wiremock-testing-mocking-over-wire-stubs/).
  - Example of a commercial tool: Traffic Parrot. It allows you to [import Swagger definition files and create stubs](https://trafficparrot.com/documentation/5.26.x/http.html#import-http-usage) that way.
- Write the stub yourself in Java. This is probably the most time-consuming option, but it allows you to be very flexible. You could build it on top of OpneSource to hit the ground running.